# Rendering speed of cola-layout in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I applied [cola-layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cola) from [cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js) on a data set of  over  **500 nodes and edges**.
The layout renders the graph and takes more than ***10 minutes*** to settle down to an open-graph.

My question is ***whether or not this is the amount of time, cola would take to display a graph with such complexity?***

In order to get a visually pleasing **(balanced)** graph like this infinite:true

within **cytoscape.js** file that I had downloaded [from here](http://js.cytoscape.org/download/cytoscape.js-2.3.9.zip).

I had set,

```
infinite: true; // for cola layout
```

---

Without which it would settled down to an entangled graph like this :
[infinite:false](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/rocha/figures/pdp1net.jpg)

**Here is the javascript code:**

```
$(function()
{
  $('#cy').cytoscape
  ({
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node').css({'content': 'data(name)'})
      .selector('edge').css({'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'})
      .selector(':selected').css({'line-color': 'black'})
    elements: {
      nodes: [
        { data: { id: '2335', name: '2335' } },
      //.
      //. data from www.briandunning.com/sample-data/ca-500.zip

    },
],
  edges: [
    { data: { source:'2335', target:'Canton' }
      //.
      //. data from www.briandunning.com/sample-data/ca-500.zip
    }]
},
  layout: { name: 'cola'},
  ready: function()
  {
    window.cy = this;
  }
});


});
```

Comment: The question does not have non opinion-based answer without seeing the anonymized dataset ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Sir. If it is the dataset you want go through then you can download the same from [Canada - 500 Records](http://briandunning.com/sample-data/ca-500.zip). The columns used to generate the graph are **phone1** as _source_ & **phone2** as _target_.  I shall edit and add my code for clarity. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have answered your own question!  If you set `infinite: true`, then the layout will run infinitely.  So, of course in that case it will run a long time, and in fact it will never stop unless you make API calls to do so explicitly.

Comment: **Sir**. I tried the same layout with a data set of around **30 nodes & edges** and got the graph generated in a **second or two**, with `infinite: true`. My question is regarding the **speed** at which the algorithm would render such a complex graph which I had mentioned earlier. I do not mind if it takes **8 mins** to render initially and then some how save the newly computed positions, and use it to restore it faster in the future. My attempt to understand & use [cy.json](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/export/cy.json) is in vain. Demos for **Exporting the graph as JSON** would be helpful.